# Angular2 read json use XMLHttpRequest.response

Tags: angular

I use XMLHttpRequest to send files to the backend, and will return json format information, how can I get each value?

code

```
this.resdata = xhr.response;
console.log("this.resdata2: " + this.resdata);
console.log("this.resdata[0]: " + this.resdata[0]);
console.log("this.resdata[1]: " + this.resdata[1]);
```

and Chrome DevTools message

```
this.resdata2: {"result":123,"gpsvalue":246}
home.component.ts:112 this.resdata[0]: {
home.component.ts:113 this.resdata[1]: "
```

How do i get resdata2 the value of result and gpsvalue and show it on my page?

Answer (score 0):

Since Response is JSON Object

use `this.resdata.result`  `// to get result value`

use `this.resdata.gpsvalue`  `// to get gpsvalue value`

Comment: show property 'gpsvalue' does not exist on type 'number' and property 'result ' does not exist on type 'number'?